# UINavigationController is nil when adding new storyboard

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I would like to add a storyboard inside existing UIViewController (something like iframe in html)

I have my MainViewController and I'm adding the storyboard view controller as a subview like this:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Search" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
SearchViewController *search = (SearchViewController *)[[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchViewController"] visibleViewController];
[self addChildViewController:search];
[self.view addSubview:search.view];
```

Now my search.storyboard have 2 view controllers and they are embedded inside navigation controller.

Now when the search view is loaded the navigation controller is nil.. :\

How can I implement this solution with using the navigation controller? Thx.

Comment: When and where did you call `self.navigationController` ?

Comment: inside the search view. in the viewdidload/ viewdidappear

Comment: Does it even return `nil` in `viewdidappear` ?

Comment: Yes, in the view did appear i check the self.navigationcontroller and its nil